# Extracting values

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have imported a data from an excel sheet.

I want to extract parts of the list based on some conditions. First I want to create one list whit the `The Coca-Cola` data and then I want another list with `McDonald` data. The key thing is that I want the extraction process to be able to spot when the data moves from one ticker to another.

```
AA = MatrixForm[DUBS]
```

> ```
> {{"Symbol", "Full Name", "Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close",   
>    "Adj Close", "Volume", "Type"},
>    {"KO", "The Coca-Cola Company", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 40.88, 41.1,
>      40.79, 41.09, 41.09, 1.14011*10^7, "Stock"},{
>    {"MCD", "McDonald", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.2, 100.41, 99.53, 
>      100.27, 100.27, 4.5083*10^6, "Stock"},
>    {"MCD", "McDonald", {2013, 7, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.48, 100.77, 99.99, 
>      100.18, 100.18, 3.4016*10^6, "Stock"},
>    {"MCD", "McDonald", {2013, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.05, 100.35, 99.3, 
>      100.1, 100.1, 5.3774*10^6, "Stock"}}
> ```

Comment: Don't have Mma on the computer I am using atm but if you know the tickers then `Cases[list,{"KO",__}]` and `Cases[list,{"MCD",__}]` should do it for extracting. To recognize change in ticker `SplitBy` will probably be your friend. See docs.

Comment: Okey, lets say that I want to use SplitBy data how would that look like given the data?

Comment: Tried applying the Cases[AA,{"KO",__}], did not work. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the list. The first entry for McDonald has two curly brackets, i.e. {{"MCD",... It should have one.  When this is corrected code for Cases works fine.

Comment: I have changed the list, it is currently working with the Cases[list,{"KO",__}] and Cases[list,{"MCD",__}] but its not working with SplitBy[list,#[[1,1]]&]

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{"Symbol", "Full Name", "Date", "Open", "High", "Low", 
    "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume", "Type"}, {"KO", 
    "The Coca-Cola Company", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 40.88, 41.1, 
    40.79, 41.09, 41.09, 1.14011*10^7, "Stock"}, {"MCD", 
    "McDonald", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.2, 100.41, 99.53, 100.27,
     100.27, 4.5083*10^6, "Stock"}, {"MCD", 
    "McDonald", {2013, 7, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.48, 100.77, 99.99, 
    100.18, 100.18, 3.4016*10^6, "Stock"}, {"MCD", 
    "McDonald", {2013, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.05, 100.35, 99.3, 100.1, 
    100.1, 5.3774*10^6, "Stock"}};
```

To extract ticker data:

```
Cases[list, {"KO", __}]
(*
{{"KO", "The Coca-Cola Company", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 40.88, 41.1,
   40.79, 41.09, 41.09, 1.14011*10^7, "Stock"}}
*)
```

Being able to "*spot when the data moves from one ticker to another*" is quit vague at present. You probably need to clarify what form this "spotting" should take but here is one way in which the "runs" of a particular ticker symbol are split:

```
SplitBy[list, First]
(*   
{{{"Symbol", "Full Name", "Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", 
   "Adj Close", "Volume", "Type"}}, {{"KO", 
   "The Coca-Cola Company", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 40.88, 41.1, 
   40.79, 41.09, 41.09, 1.14011*10^7, "Stock"}}, {{"MCD", 
   "McDonald", {2013, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.2, 100.41, 99.53, 100.27, 
   100.27, 4.5083*10^6, "Stock"}, {"MCD", 
   "McDonald", {2013, 7, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.48, 100.77, 99.99, 100.18,
    100.18, 3.4016*10^6, "Stock"}, {"MCD", 
   "McDonald", {2013, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 100.05, 100.35, 99.3, 100.1, 
   100.1, 5.3774*10^6, "Stock"}}}

*)
```

Or alternatively

```
Length /@ SplitBy[list, First]

(* {1, 1, 3} *)
```

...so we need some clarification about what you would like to see to spot when the data moves from one ticker symbol to another.